# Собрать проект как несколько разных приложений

Tags: java, android, gradle

У меня есть проект в android studio. Мне надо собрать его как 20 почти одинаковых приложений, у которых будет отличатся только иконка и картинка в main activity. Как это сделать быстро и просто?

Comment: Flavors: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Comment: В maven есть такое как Profile, может в Gradle есть похожее